# NodeJs + PhantomJs return JQuery result from page.evaluate method

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs

NodeJS newbie here. I am trying to parse html with using NodeJS and PhamtomJS ([phantomjs-node](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node)). When I run the the JQuery `$("[class*='question-summary']")` from the browser console it returns an array. However, I couldn't manage to do the same thing on nodejs. I guess stackoverflow has JQuery so I don't need to use `includeJs` to load jquery. Actually, when I run

Here is the nodejs example I am running;

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

async function getHtml() {
    const instance = await phantom.create([
        "--load-images=false"    
    ]);

    const page = await instance.createPage();
    await page.on("onResourceRequested", function(requestData) {
        console.info('Requesting', requestData.url)
    });

    const status = await page.open('http://stackoverflow.com');
    console.log("STATUS: " + status);

    const content = await page.property('content');
    console.log(content);

    var result = await page.evaluate(function(content) {
                    return $("[class*='question-summary']");
                 });

    console.log("Result : " + result);
    await instance.exit();
};

getHtml();
```

I run with the command `>node --harmony-async-await phantomTest.js`. And the process gets stuck after printing content to console.

Comment: I suppose node.js is a hard requirement? it's just that doing this in PhantomJS would be soooo much simpler.

Comment: it is not a hard a requirement but I will try to implement a cron job for parsing and persisting some data. and I want to learn nodejs.

Comment: I just wanted to note that you can write scripts spicifically for PhantomJS, run them from cron and they will be MUCH simpler, without  async/await/promises stuff.

Comment: thanks @Vaviloff I found a simple way to return something from evaluate function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here. Creating an array inside evaluate function and pushing elements inside worked. I guess the only limitation is `phantom-node` just supports returning objects with primitives.

```
var result = await page.evaluate(function() {
    var questionSummaries = [];
    $("[class*='question-summary']").each(function() {
        questionSummaries.push(this.innerHTML);
    });
    return questionSummaries;
});
```